# How to continue entering commands on SSH-server, using expect

Tags: linux, ssh, tcl, expect

I'm using `expect` to connect on my SSH-server:

```
#!/bin/expect

set command [lindex $argv 0]
set command_connect "connect"

proc connect {} {
    spawn ssh username@192.168.1.101
    expect "password"
    send "password\r"
    interact
}

if {$command == $command_connect} {
    connect
}
```

All good working and I'm can connect to server, but I can't enter commands! Somehow all commands entering on my computer! If I try to clear screen:

```
proc connect {} {
    spawn ssh username@192.168.1.101
    expect "password"
    send "password\r"
    spawn clear
    interact
}
```

Then I clear screen on my computer and SSH-connection disconnect (I returned to my console)!

---

Why is this happening and how continue enter commands on SSH-server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send commands to the remote server, then you need to send them through the spawned SSH process:

```
expect "$"
send "clear\r"
```

The first line is to ensure the prompt on the remote server appeared.

Comment: I has new question, maybe You can me help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38547629/how-does-i-know-whether-the-console-control-is-returned

Answer (score 1):

Also, because you're `spawn`ing inside a procedure, the `spawn_id` variable will have *local* scope. If you intend to encapsulate the connection inside the proc, but be able to work with the spawned process outside of the procedure, you'll need to add `global spawn_id` to the procedure body.